# Have any app for download YouTube and Facebook video?

Tags: facebook, video, youtube

I need to download YouTube and Facebook videos.
How to do this? Please help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, have many of online app for Download YouTube and Facebook video.

You can try http://downvdo.aiobd.com/ for do it.

Go to the App and paste your YouTube or Facebook video link on text box and click Generate Download link. A video file loading on your browser. right click upper on video and click **save video as** .

Hope it helpful for you.

Comment: You can also use [savefbvideo.net](https://savefbvideo.net)  to download facebook video.